# Jasypt with Spring fails to load Bean

Tags: spring, jasypt

I am trying to integrate Jasypt with Spring to load the properties file .

I am using the following 
class="org.jasypt.spring3.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

instead of the Spring provided placeholder .

Although I have provided all the configurations correctly as the same configurations work in  a different Web project that I own . But it fails in the Java project with the following error .

```
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:172)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

Can somebody tell me as to what can cause the issue ??

Comment: You should provide a better stack trace, we cannot see any message

Comment: farvilain - I could figure out the cause ... this happens while the LoggerLevel in the load properties method of PropertiesLoaderSupport of core Spring is set to Info while we use Jasypt and this throws the error . Can you suggest if I can change the Logging level in Jasypt .